# Imperavi Redactor content not being copied over to hidden textarea

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3, textarea, redactor

I'm trying to use the [Imperavi Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) control for my rich text editing here:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_area :description, :class => "richtext" %>
  </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.richtext').redactor();
});
```

The rich text editor appears and works fine, however when I type in content, I can see using the Inspect Element in Google Chrome that the html markup is not being copied over to the hidden text area. See:

```
<div class="controls">
    //Removed toolbar for brevity.
    <div class="redactor_box">
        <div class="redactor_richtext redactor_editor" contenteditable="true" dir="ltr"><p>asdfjoiasjdf</p><p>dfjiasdfjiasd</p><p>idsfj</p><p>asdffaas</p></div>
    </div>

    <textarea class="richtext" cols="40" id="program_description" name="program[description]" rows="20" style="display: none;"></textarea></div>
</div>
```

When doing a form POST of this textarea nothing is visible to the server obviously, because the textarea is blank.

Any suggestions on how to have the rich html copied over to the textarea? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try build-in function `$().syncCode()`

```
syncCode: function()
{
    var html = this.formatting(this.$editor.html());
    this.$el.val(html);         
}
```

Or `$().setCode()`

```
setCode: function(html)
{
    html = this.preformater(html);

    this.$editor.html(html).focus();

    this.syncCode();
},
```

Comment: Are these built-in functions? I'm having the same problem. I change the text is the editor and the hidden textarea does not reflect the changes in the Chrome Dev Tools...

Comment: @Jakobud Yes, ```setCode()``` and ```syncCode()``` is built-in methods, see: [syncCode](https://github.com/orloffv/imperavi-redactor/search?utf8=✓&q=syncCode) and [setCode](https://github.com/orloffv/imperavi-redactor/search?utf8=✓&q=setCode)

Comment: I think I must have been using an old version because I updated and it worked. Thanks.